# Rails API Offline Documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get an offline version of the Rails API documentation found at [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org). Most places I check refer me to [railsapi.com](http://railsapi.com) but it looks like the site is no longer used. I tried using the rdoc server that comes with RubyGems but it's hideous and difficult to navigate.

So, Is there a repository, gem or zip file containing the docs for offline viewing? Similar to [jQAPI](http://jqapi.com)?

Comment: This question does not belong on StackOverflow. The question should pertain to code you are trying to write and you need to show that you've made an effort to solve a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/passion8/Rails-4-offline-documentation

This worked just fine, with a one-click download that gave me a zip file. Just extract the contents and open the index.html file, and you have a local copy of the Rails 4 API that works exactly like the online copy.

It looks like this is new and is only 4 months old.

Comment: Thanks. I had already used WGet but this is much neater

Comment: Zip file is 3.0 MB, for the curious.

Answer (score 6):

Try `wget -r -k -p http://api.rubyonrails.org/`. It should help you with the offline api.

Comment: I'm on a windows machine. so I don't have wget

Comment: I was able to download [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) thanks

Comment: Now how to read it locally after downloading ?

Comment: The doc will be downloaded as api.rubyonrails.org. Get into the directory and open index.html in browser.

Comment: Downloading guides is just one parameter away: wget -r -k -p -L http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.3/ (-L to stay with the specified version) Then you can view them with i.e. Python's built in web server. An example script of mine here: https://gist.github.com/vadviktor/031be4663562d361f79b

Answer (score 2):

You could use the rails github repo:

- Checkout or download the desired version from https://github.com/rails/rails
- `cd your_rails_directory`
- `bundle`
- `rake rdoc`

Then open the file `doc\index.html` in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

**API:**

```
rake doc:rails
```

**Guides:**

```
gem install 'RedCloth'
rake doc:guides
```